Wema API test fail
I'm working with Wema onboarding open API and I have been trying to test and API before I use it in my project but I keep getting the
error:

Internal Server Error => Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'client').

Here is the request body, I'm still getting the error even after I have filled the body properly with the required credentials:

